# How can I create and customize delivery channel notification in Laravel like database and email?

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, customization

I'm create a delivery channel in Laravel like this:

```
public function via($notifiable){
    return [SmsChannel::class,MailChannel::class,TelChannel::class];
}
```

but I need it to be like this:

```
public function via($notifiable){
    return ['sms','mail','telegram'];
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must create your own service provider for it and register your channels. Like this:

```
class YouChannelRegisterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $channels = [
            'telegram' => TelChannel::class,
            'sms' => SmsChannel::class,
            ...
        ];

        foreach($channels as $name => $className) {
            Notification::extend($name, function () use ($className) {
                return new $className;
            });
        }
    }
}
```